# Conflict while merging two branches to third branch

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

If there are two branches out of Master, lets say #10 and #11. 
I want to merge them into a new branch #dev6.

> #10 has successfully merged with #dev6 while merging #11 to #dev6
>   conflict occurs

I want every piece of CODE FROM BOTH BRANCHES #10 and #11 to be merged in #dev6.

How to do that?

Comment: Are you using any mergetool for merging ?